# How can I sort that table in Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, sorting, csv, dictionary

```
import sys, subprocess, glob

mdbfiles = glob.glob('*.res')
for DATABASE in mdbfiles: 

    subprocess.call(["mdb-schema", DATABASE, "mysql"])

    table_names = subprocess.Popen(["mdb-tables", "-1", DATABASE],
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    tables = table_names.splitlines()

    sys.stdout.flush()

    a=str('Channel_Normal_Table')

    for table in tables:
        if table != '' and table==a:

            filename = DATABASE.replace(".res","") + ".csv"
            file = open(filename, 'w')
            print("Dumping " + table)
            contents = subprocess.Popen(["mdb-export", DATABASE, table],
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

            # I NEED TO PUT SOMETHING HERE TO SORT AND EXTRACT THE DATA I NEED


            file.write(contents)
            file.close()
```

I have a table extracted from database. Lets call it `table`. I need to perform the following operations and I got a bit stuck:

```
Cycle Test_Time  Current    Voltage
1     7.80E-002 0.00E+000   1.21E-001
1     3.01E+001 0.00E+000   1.19E-001
1     6.02E+001 0.00E+000   1.17E-001
2     9.02E+001 0.00E+000   1.14E-001
2     1.20E+002 0.00E+000   1.11E-001
2     1.50E+002 0.00E+000   1.08E-001
2     1.80E+002 0.00E+000   1.05E-001
2     2.10E+002 0.00E+000   1.02E-001
3     2.40E+002 0.00E+000   9.93E-002
3     2.70E+002 0.00E+000   9.66E-002
3     3.00E+002 0.00E+000   9.38E-002
3     3.10E+002 4.00E-001   1.26E+000
```

1. Extract the just last (latest) row of each cycle or, more advanced, sort the cycle
   by time and extract the row of the cycle with the latest time. As
   you can see, last row does not always have the latest time due to
   our testing machine glitch, but usually does. But the bigger the
   number the later the time.
2. Extract all the rows for the last five cycles
3. Extract all the rows from cycle 4 to cycle 30.

I tried various methods, like creating and sorting dictionaries and lists based on my limited Python  knowledge but none of them resulted to the desired output. It just drives me nuts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to take a look at Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: These are incredibly simple tasks using awk and  other shell utilities

Comment: why cant you do this in the database itself ?

Comment: Guys. This is the project I have to finish. We are converting scripts from bash to Python. I have .mdb files that I need to process. So I was able to extract necessary table, but I need to sort that able and extract particular data. I am not a programmer and have little knowledge of Python so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so hard, but you have to take it step-by-step:

```
from collections import defaultdict

table = """\
Cycle Test_Time  Current    Voltage
1     7.80E-002 0.00E+000   1.21E-001
1     3.01E+001 0.00E+000   1.19E-001
1     6.02E+001 0.00E+000   1.17E-001
2     9.02E+001 0.00E+000   1.14E-001
2     1.20E+002 0.00E+000   1.11E-001
2     1.50E+002 0.00E+000   1.08E-001
2     1.80E+002 0.00E+000   1.05E-001
2     2.10E+002 0.00E+000   1.02E-001
3     2.40E+002 0.00E+000   9.93E-002
3     2.70E+002 0.00E+000   9.66E-002
3     3.00E+002 0.00E+000   9.38E-002
3     3.10E+002 4.00E-001   1.26E+000"""

# Split into rows
table = table.splitlines()

# Split each row into values
table = [row.split() for row in table]

# Associate the column names with their index
headers = table.pop(0)
H = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(headers)}
time_index = H["Test_Time"]
cycle_index = H["Cycle"]

# Sort by Test_Time
table.sort(key=lambda row: float(row[time_index]))

# Associate each test with its cycle
D = defaultdict(list)
for row in table:
  D[int(row[cycle_index])].append(row)

# Present the information
print(*headers, sep='\t')
print("Latest row for each cycle")
for cycle in sorted(D.keys()):
  tests = D[cycle]
  latest_test = tests[-1]
  print(*latest_test, sep='\t')

print("All rows for last 5 cycles")
for cycle in sorted(D.keys())[-5:]:
  tests = D[cycle]
  for test in tests:
    print(*test, sep='\t')

print("All rows for cycles 4 through 30")
for cycle in sorted(D.keys()):
    if 4 <= cycle <= 30:
      tests = D[cycle]
      for test in tests:
        print(*test, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it right now. Another thing. How can save that processed content into .csv file?

Comment: Check out the python [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: I am getting an error:       'alphanumeric characters and underscores: %r' % name)
ValueError: Type names and field names can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores: 'Test_ID,Data_Point,Test_Time,Step_Time,DateTime,Step_Index,Cycle_Index,Is_FC_Data,Current,Voltage,Charge_Capacity,Discharge_Capacity,Charge_Energy,Discharge_Energy,dV/dt,Internal_Resistance,AC_Impedance,ACI_Phase_Angle'

Comment: Try changing the namedtuple line to `namedtuple("table_row", headers, rename=True)`. You seem to be using different headers from the sample file? Also be sure to accept the answer if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, i am using different headers, since the whole table is like 26 columns long and can have million of rows. 
I added the True statement but now I am getting another error:     table = [table_row(int(c), float(t), float(i), float(v)) for c, t, i, v in table[1:]]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> 

Sure I will accept the answer. I just need to make that script work. Been battling with it for the whole day with no results. I am kinda new to Python and all that stuff looks very complicated to me as of now ((

Comment: My solution depended on the structure of the data in the sample table. I modified it to be more generic. Try that?

Comment: No, no luck. Is it for Python 3 or 2? I am stuck with printing error now.     print(*test, sep='\t')
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Add `from __future__ import print_function` to the very top. I wrote it for Python 3.

Comment: Nope, same thing. Zero output. Basically what I did is extracted a table from .mdb file, now I need to sort that table, but none of the methods works!!! I can print the the whole table. I can save it as .CSV but once I try to filter it nothing works. I am about to give up.

Comment: Upload a segment of the CSV file somewhere?

Comment: I run a script that extracts a table from .mdb file. Then I try to sort that table, but nothing works so far. I can print that table or save it to .csv but what I need is to sort that table and save only the data I need. I added to my original  posting the script code I run.

Comment: I wanted to see a sample of the data to see if there was something that was causing the script to fail when processing. If all you're getting is the print error then you're either using an old Python without print_function or you need to just adapt the output parts.

Comment: I can dump the data into .csv and then reopen CSV but I d preffer to skip that step and get extracted data directly. Here is the link to the file i get after dumping table from database:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8mzw2uh055ok4d/VC0307a.csv

Comment: Your script worked. The problem, as I mentioned, is in transition from .mdb file into proper table. If I just type the table as in your example, the script works like a charm, but if I try to associate the table I extracted from .mdb (like table=contents), then it does not work. Thanks a lot! I m getting a bit more familiar with Python now.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily done your job with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [pymdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymdb)

With pandas, you can handle your time series data with no pain.
Just take a look at pandas.DataFrame. That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's read the file and convert the values found into ints for the cycle col and floats for the rest:

```
databyrow=[]
with open('/tmp/temps.txt', 'r') as f:
    header=f.readline().strip().split()
    for line in f:
        temp=[]
        for i,val in enumerate(line.strip().split()):
            fn=int if i==0 else float
            try:
                val=fn(val)
            except ValueError:
                print val,'not converted'
            temp.append(val)    
        databyrow.append(temp)                
print databyrow
```

Prints:

```
 [[1, 0.078, 0.0, 0.121],
 [1, 30.1, 0.0, 0.119],
 [1, 60.2, 0.0, 0.117],
 [2, 90.2, 0.0, 0.114],
 [2, 120.0, 0.0, 0.111],
 [2, 150.0, 0.0, 0.108],
 [2, 180.0, 0.0, 0.105],
 [2, 210.0, 0.0, 0.102],
 [3, 240.0, 0.0, 0.0993],
 [3, 270.0, 0.0, 0.0966],
 [3, 300.0, 0.0, 0.0938],
 [3, 310.0, 0.4, 1.26]]
```

Now you can create a group dictionary based on the cycle col list in the list of lists just created:

```
from itertools import groupby
keyfn=lambda t:t[0]
sorted_input=sorted(databyrow,key=keyfn)
data_bycycle={k:list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted_input,key=keyfn)}
```

Prints:

```
{1: [[1, 0.078, 0.0, 0.121], [1, 30.1, 0.0, 0.119], [1, 60.2, 0.0, 0.117]], 
 2: [[2, 90.2, 0.0, 0.114], [2, 120.0, 0.0, 0.111], [2, 150.0, 0.0, 0.108], [2, 180.0, 0.0, 0.105], [2, 210.0, 0.0, 0.102]], 
 3: [[3, 240.0, 0.0, 0.0993], [3, 270.0, 0.0, 0.0966], [3, 300.0, 0.0, 0.0938], [3, 310.0, 0.4, 1.26]]}
```

Now you can get your last N rows of each cycle directly:

```
>>> N=2
>>> data_bycycle[1][-N:]
[[1, 30.1, 0.0, 0.119], [1, 60.2, 0.0, 0.117]]
```

If you want one of that group sorted by the latest time:

```
>>> sorted(data_bycycle[2],key=lambda li: li[1])[-1]
[2, 210.0, 0.0, 0.102]
```

---

### *Edit*

Downloading the linked dropbox file, you have a csv file -- not space delimited.

Here is how to read something like that:

```
import csv

databyrow=[]
with open('/tmp/VC0307a.csv', 'r') as f:      # potentially you can use 'contents' here
    for i,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        if i==0:
            header=row
        else:
            temp=[]
            for j,val in enumerate(row):
                fn=int if j in (0,1) else float
                try:
                    val=fn(val)
                except ValueError:
                    print val, 'not converted'
                temp.append(val)     
            databyrow.append(temp)
```

Once you have it in memory, you can sort by a certain numerical column:

```
>>> header
['Test_ID', 'Data_Point', 'Test_Time', 'Step_Time', 'DateTime', 'Step_Index', 'Cycle_Index', 'Is_FC_Data', 'Current', 'Voltage', 'Charge_Capacity', 'Discharge_Capacity', 'Charge_Energy', 'Discharge_Energy', 'dV/dt', 'Internal_Resistance', 'AC_Impedance', 'ACI_Phase_Angle']

>>> n=header.index('Test_Time') 
>>> by_time=sorted(databyrow,key=lambda t: t[n])
```

Comment: I am getting empty output in here when printing (((

Comment: Which part of the printout?

Comment: I am just about to give up with that battle. Didnt know that sorting a table from mdb file can become such a complicated task in Python[]
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dump3.py", line 55, in <module>
    data_bycycle[1.0][-N:]
KeyError: 1.0    Basically I am just getting a blank screen. Even previous Print lines produce blank output.

Comment: What keys are in the dict data_bycycle? Try `print data_bycycle.keys()`

Comment: OK, there is some kind of an error at the begining where I try to pass the content of extracted table. I just opened a sample .txt file and got some output. But at the end I am still getting an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dump3.py", line 55, in <module>
    data_bycycle[1.0][-N:]
KeyError: 1.0

Comment: What keys are in the dict data_bycycle? Try print data_bycycle.keys()

Comment: Same error:      data_bycycle[1.0][-N:]
KeyError: 1.0

Comment: You get that error because the key `2.0` does not exist. You didn't answer my question: what keys ARE in data_bycycle? You can get that by putting a `print data_bycycle.keys()`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by keys. When I run the script I am getting an error:     data_bycycle[1][-N:]
KeyError: When I just run print data_bycycle.keys() from console the whole file gets printed.

Comment: OK, I started getting some output. If I dont know the total number of cycles how can I print (save to csv) the latest row of each cycle and how can I print (save) the whole data for the latest (or first) 5 cycles or the data for cycles 50-90? It started making sense to me. I will need the whole data for last 5 cycles to create plots  of V and I vs time.  Thanks a bunch.